# Unexpected Token Import when serving public js file from /node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typed.js

I'm trying to run typed.js on my homepage for a headline.  On its website it gives installation [instructions for npm, bower, and grun](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/)t.  I installed it via npm.

To make it accessible as a static file I added the following line to my `app.js` file:

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/typed.js/src/'));
```

This works fine.

However, when it's read from the browser, I get the error mentioned in the question title.

It pertains to the first two lines of the file:

```
import { initializer } from './initializer.js';
import { htmlParser } from './html-parser.js';
```

These are two other files found in `node_modules/typed.js/src`.

I understand that if this file was being interpreted on the server the `import` command would not be an issue.

However, AFAIK I have to serve this file from the browser in order for it to be rendered at all.

How do you import code from another javascript file in the browser?

Or does this have to be interpreted on the server?

I'm not using babel or mocha or anything else when trying to deliver this file, unlike many of the other questions on this topic.

Comment: You need to use webpack or browserify or a similar tool to "convert" modular javascript into browser-compatible javascript.

Comment: Is there one that's most suitable for a beginner?

Comment: Try webpack: https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/#modules